# Chaining of methods with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with the first column made up of checkboxes. I want to collect the values of the checked rows with jquery and transmit these to a aphp function for processing .

So far I have:

```
var searchIDs = $('input:checked').map(function(){
                  return $(this).val();
                });
```

which returns an object containing the checked values.

I can get an array of these using :

```
searchIDs.get()
```

of the form :

1,2,3 etc

However if I do :

```
   return $((this).val()).get();
```

I get:

```
TypeError: this.val is not a function
```

Why do I not get the array listed above? How can I get this working in a single statement?

Comment: What is `this` in context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.map works its way through the jQuery object's array-like list of checkboxes, creating a similar jQuery array-like object with your [1,2,3] within it. So the trick is to add the chained get() right at the end, then you will successfully call it once map() has completed building your list of IDs:

```
var searchIDs = $('input:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

eg

http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/3k7oy3dq/

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that a jQuery selection can be traversed if it were an array of DOM elements. You can access the value of an [`input` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties) by looking at the `value` property.

```js
var $checked  = $('input:checked'),
    searchIDs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $checked.length; i++) {
  searchIDs.push($checked[i].value);
}
```